# How to Delay canvas rendering of webpage to allow elements to load?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas, jspdf

I am using html2canvas to capture the webpage as a jpeg, and then jsPDF to convert that to pdf doc. I am facing issue in caputring the webpage where, the webpage is captured before few charts are loaded. But in the browser, befor triggering this function, all the graphs are loaded. These charts use other js libraries like d3, jVectorMap. Is there a way I can delay the rendering?

I used this link for reference:

- http://springtricks.blogspot.sg/2013/10/how-to-download-charts-to-pdf-formate.html
- http://www.dannyoosterveer.nl/test_canvas2pdf/canvas2pdf.html

The function I am using:

```
function export_PDF() {
    //convert whole html page to canvas  
            html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element

            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG").slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);

            // Convert the data to binary form
                            myImage = atob(myImage);

            //new object of jspdf and save image to pdf.

                            var doc = new jsPDF();
                            doc.addImage(myImage, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 180,200);
                            doc.save('pdfName.pdf');
        }
            });

}
```

I tried this code, but dint help me as its not delaying the rendering but just the creation of canvas:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
"onrendered": function(canvas) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       //my code
    }, 5000);
}
});
```

Comment: "..the webpage is captured before few charts are loaded. But in the browser, befor triggering this function, all the graphs are loaded..." So are the graphs loaded or not?

Comment: @AndreiDvoynos This export_pdf is triggered on a button click. I click the button from my browser only after the graphs are loaded. But, In the canvas image and generated pdf - Incomplete charts.

Comment: Then the problem is probably not going to be solved by delaying the call to the Export_Pdf function. It's more likely something to do with html2canvas not working properly. Are the graphs generated by your javascript rendered as svg? If so, when calling Html2Canvas, try setting the allowTaint property to true.